# "Solve" command in MATLAB returns solution in terms of 'z'? What is 'z' here?

Tags: matlab

(MATLAB 2010 A Student version)

Question: 
I am trying to solve 9 symbolic equations with 9 symbolic variables using "solve" command:

Problem:

```
N=2

V = sym(zeros(N+2+1)); % 5*5 symbolic matrix

syms D x; %D is diffusion constant

%Creating 3*3 non-zero symbolic entries
for row = 0:N
    for col = 0:N
        V(row+1, col+1) = sym(sprintf('V%d%d', row+1, col+1));
    end
end

count=1;
for m=0:N
    for n=0:N
        % Diffusion PDE written in Differential Transform domain
        eqn(count) = (m+1)*V(m+1+1,n+1)-D*(n+1)*(n+2)*V(m+1,n+2+1);  
        count=count+1;
    end
end

%length(eqn) is 9

eqn=eqn(1:7);      %as last 2 terms are [0 0] in eqn
```

Initial condition for PDE are given by Dirac Delta func ("delta(x)"). Thus, it is composed of 2 conditions (one for x=0 and one for x not equal to 0)

Thus, at x=0, it is "1"  giving:

```
eqn(length(eqn)+1)=V(1,1)-V(2,1)+V(3,1)-1; % ini.condn
```

And at x NOT equal to 0, it is "0"  giving: (does it make sense?)

```
eqn(length(eqn)+1)=(V(1,1)-V(2,1)+V(3,1))+(V(1,2)-V(2,2)+V(3,2))*x + (V(1,3)-     
V(2,3)+V(3,3))*x^2; %ini. condn

S=solve(eqn,'V11' ,'V12' ,'V13' ,'V21' ,'V22' ,'V23' ,'V31' ,'V32' ,'V33');
```

Answer: S.V11, S.V12, S.V13, S.V21 are functions of 'z'. Rest are 0

I am getting 'z' in my solutions.

1. What is 'z' in the solution? What's the source of this?
2. How to circumvent this and get meaningful solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z` parameter means for whatever value of `z` you substitute in, your set of solutions is valid for your equations.

You have nine equations to find nine unknowns. However your sixth equation `2*V33=0` renders the following equation `-2*D*V33=0` redundant...so you actually only have eight independent equations, hence the extra parameter `z`. I don't know more about the details about your PDE to tell you why it isn't well-posed, but basically you need another equation involving your nonzero variables if you expect a unique solution.

Comment: Thanks RussH.. indeed i had missed accounting for an extra IC..In fact, I have a doubt on Dirac Delta func Initial condn in my PDE prob(1D diffusion eqn)..It states at x=0, value is 1, and else(x values), value is 0, rite?..This means, Do I have 2 ini.condns (one for x=0 and one for rest x) or only ONE ini.condn (only x=0 value is 1)? Confused!! How do people incorporate such dirac delta func ini.condns in applications (any pde say).does it count for 1 condition or 2 conditions basically?

Comment: I think we would need more information about your PDE and its coefficients to provide any helpful advice. You might want to try looking at variational methods for solving your PDE, I think you have more of a PDE problem than a MATLAB problem.

Comment: @ems: did this answer your question? if yes you might want to click the 'Accept' checkmark, if not, some more detail about what you need would be nice.

Comment: & others..Thanks..I asked if you could say, if Dirac Delta initial condition composes of 2 conditions or only (1st condn:takes value 1 at x=0, 2nd condition:takes value 0, if x not equal to 0). is it necessary to treat this dirac delta func initial condition for PDE as ONE or TWO separate conditions?? anyone??

Comment: Well it's only one condition, but it may help to write out the PDE you are trying to solve. They might also be of help over at math.stackexchange.com.